# Unable to convert tweets to JSON format and then save as text file

Tags: python-3.x, tweets

I am trying to create a json object which I then want to save an a text file where each tweet's JSON data representing its own line. This is what I have but its not working:

```
#Connect to Twitter API:
import tweepy
consumer_key = 'xx'
consumer_secret = 'xx'
access_token = 'xxx'
access_secret = 'xx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

tweets=[]
#pull first entry only for testing
for i in df_image_pred.tweet_id[0:1]:
    t=api.get_status(i, tweet_mode='extended',wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
    tweets.append(t._json)

#save as text file
f = open("dict.txt","w")
f.write( str(tweets) )
f.close()
```

The output is this:
[image]

When read the text file in pandas, this is my output in a dataframe which is the issue here:
[image]

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @ExplodingGayFish I want to extract three columns: retweet_count and full_text, and id as a dataframe. How would I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using `pandas`? if `tweets` is a list of `dict`, you can simply use `pd.DataFrame(tweets)`

Comment: @ExplodingGayFish when i do that, it returns 1 column which includes all values, thus no recognized seperation. There is no normalization in the text file, so pandas cannot understand it I think. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: You mean after reading from `dict.txt` or is your `tweets` an array of strings instead of array of dicts?

Comment: The former case you can use the `json` module like [`here`](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/), the latter you can use the built-in function [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: I am not sure why my question is not clear. I will try again. I pulled twitter data as a json object and then saved it in a text file. Now I need to read the data as a dataframe but since the json was not serialized, the dict structre remains and I cannot create a clean dataframe. What do i do? Since I have 1000s of key value pairs for each column, I canot do this manually. I added the df img in post.

Comment: Why do you need to save into a text file? You can convert the json object straght into a dataframe (`pd.DataFrame(tweets)`). But if you want to convert a dataframe from a text file like yours, you will first need to convert it back to a json object (`json.load`)